# How to run jslint command on all files with in a directory in cmd (context npm)

Tags: npm, jslint

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/reid/node-jslint/+/pulls-2013-11-03/doc/jslint.md

the above link is a the documentation on jslint. I am trying to run the jslint command on all the js files available with in a directory and subdirectories in a command prompt.

I don't find any option. even if i try to run the command by passing directory as a param. i am getting error. Any solutions will be very helpful.

jslint src/
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Note: src is a source directory which has all my js files in sub directories.

Answer (score 0):

instructions to jslint a directory is [here](https://github.com/jslint-org/jslint#4-to-jslint-entire-directory).  it will only shallow lint directory however.